Android - How to schedule a Job requiring Network Capability while under a VPN
I am trying to setup a JobScheduler that runs a JobService to download a file under certain conditions.
It's working like a charm but i can't make it work while under a VPN.
I've tried to change the capabilities but nothing works.
I've tried multiple VPNs, it never works.
Here is the code of my use case launching the JobService.
/**
 * A use case for downloading a replay.
 *
 * This use case schedules a download job using the `JobScheduler`.
 * The download job is handled by the `DownloadJobService`.
 *
 */
class DownloadReplayUseCase @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext private val context: Context,
    private val moshi: Moshi,
) : (Replay) -> Unit {

    companion object {
        private const val DOWNLOAD_JOB_ID_START = 10001
        private const val DOWNLOAD_JOB_ID_END = 20000
        private var currentJobId = DOWNLOAD_JOB_ID_START

        private const val MAXIMUM_SCHEDULING_LATENCY = 1000L
    }

    /**
     * Schedules a download job for the given replay.
     *
     * @param replay The replay to download.
     */
    override fun invoke(replay: Replay) {
        val networkRequest = NetworkRequest.Builder()
            .addCapability(NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
            .addCapability(NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED)
            .build()

        val bundle = PersistableBundle().apply {
            putString(DownloadJobService.REPLAY_JSON_KEY, ReplayJsonAdapter(moshi).toJson(replay))
        }

        val jobId = currentJobId++

        if (jobId > DOWNLOAD_JOB_ID_END) {
            currentJobId = DOWNLOAD_JOB_ID_START
        }

        val jobInfoBuilder = JobInfo.Builder(
            jobId, ComponentName(context, DownloadJobService::class.java),
        ).setExtras(bundle)

        val jobInfo = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.UPSIDE_DOWN_CAKE) {
            jobInfoBuilder
                .setRequiredNetwork(networkRequest)
                .setUserInitiated(true)
                .build()
        } else {
            jobInfoBuilder
                .setOverrideDeadline(MAXIMUM_SCHEDULING_LATENCY)
                .build()
        }

        val jobScheduler: JobScheduler = context.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE) as JobScheduler
        jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo)
    }
}

When on a basic network everything work as expected, and my DownloadJobService is launched immediatly.
However, when i'm using a VPN, nothing happens. It's just queued until i stop the VPN.
Any help would be welcome !

Does the VPN allow access to the Internet? Or is it a VPN that only goes to some internal network?

In your code, you have .addCapability(NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_VPN). When used with JobInfo.Builder, this says "only run the job when we have a network that is not on a VPN". You are reporting that the job only runs when you are not on a VPN. So, it would appear as though the code is working as documented.
That documentation states:

Indicates that this network is not a VPN. This capability is set by default and should be explicitly cleared for VPN networks.

That suggests that you should try .removeCapability(NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_VPN) instead.

Sorry this is a mistake after a lot of different try.
But event without NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_VPN it's all the same, my job isn't launched

@Fabien: You edited the code, but the edited code does not use removeCapability(NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_VPN). Quoting the documentation for NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_VPN: "This capability is set by default and should be explicitly cleared for VPN networks".
